# Remove colon if not between digits

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
$str = "xxx:'2015-10-09 15:05'";

$patterns[0] = '/:/';
$patterns[1] = '/\'/';
$patterns[2] = '/xxx/';

var_dump( preg_replace($patterns, '', $str) );
```

This outputs: string(15) "2015-10-09 1505"

But I need string(16) "2015-10-09 15:05"

Comment: Why not search for the date? `\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}` ?

Comment: In addition to @Rizier123 comment, you'll need to use `preg_match()`

Comment: @Rizier123 will that also work if `2015-10-09` but can also be `2015-10-09 15:05` or `2015-10-09 15:05:37`? `$str` is an input field ...

Comment: `'/(?<!\d):(?!\d)/'` too difficult for some reason?

Comment: If your date is always in single quotes then you can split on single quote and get `$arr[1]`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol that is not working :(

Comment: @anubhava (facepalm) thanks that's probably the most easy idea! didn't think about that .. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that your input string is:

1) beginning with `xxx:'`
  2) ending with `'`

and you need everything in between the apostrophes, you may use `preg_replace` with the `/^xxx:'([^']*)'$/` regex:

```
$str = "xxx:'2015-10-09 15:05'";
var_dump( preg_replace("/^xxx:'([^']*)'$/", '$1', $str) );
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/JWLlCi)

Output: `string(16) "2015-10-09 15:05"`.

Or as an alternative, use [matching regex](https://ideone.com/C4pDm3):

```
$str = "xxx:'2015-10-09 15:05'";
if (preg_match("/(?<=')[^']+/", $str, $m)) { 
 var_dump( $m );
}
```

Here, `(?<=')[^']+` will match 1 or more characters other than a single apostrophe (`[^']+`) right after a single apostrophe (`(?<=')`).

Comment: How to check for single and or double quotes?

Comment: You may use this branch reset powered regex: [`^xxx:(?|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')$`](https://regex101.com/r/aD0pO0/1). Here is [an IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/4Lctf5). Note that the `/m` modifier is only for the demo purposes.